# Classification of Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need a little help on solving matrices. I actually just want to confirm my answer

Given matrices :

$$
A=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 0 & 8 & 9 & 7 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 7 & 6 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
B=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 0 & 8 & 9 & 7 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 7 & 6 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
C=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 0 & 8 & 9 & 7 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 6 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

Which of the following are in reduced row echelon form ?

My answer is all the matrices are *not* in reduced row echelon form. Matrices B and C are in echelon form, but not matrix A.

Am I correct ?

Comment: There is no need to write "solved" in the title; there is a green indicator on the questions that have an accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you Zev Chonoles for telling me that. I usually write SOLVED if the question is answered. Thank again Zev =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the difference for you between echelon form (E.F.) and *reduced* E.F. (R.E.F.)? The latter must have $\,1'$s on the main diagonal or what?

If so then you're right: (b)-(c) are in E.F., none in R.E.F. (a) is not even triangular so not in E.F., either.

Comment: echelon form in actually the gaussian elimination and row reduced echelon form is Gauss Jordan elimination. So my answer no problem right? because this is my assignment question

Comment: Again, names say not much. Read carefully my answer about the 1's. If your defintiions are different then I can't say.

Comment: the one you said 1's on the main diagonal is R.E.F and E.F is the more zero proceed then the previous row

Comment: I didn't understand your last words in the last comment, but it seems to be that: REF is the same as EF but with 1's on the main diagonal *and these are the only non-zero entries in that column*. So yes, your answer still holds.

Comment: Sorry I couldnt deliver what I trying to say to you. But what you said in the last comment is the one I trying to say. So again thank you very much DonAntonio for guiding me throughout the question. You really help me on my assignment.=)